# SVG graphic in FPDF

Tags: pdf, svg, fpdf

I need SVG data to print to an FPDF generated PDF. I'm bringing in said data from a post variable named $svg. When I try and write the variable to the page I get the entire data in text, not as an image (as expected), is there a way to get FPDF to draw the $svg on to the PDF? Below is my terrible attempt. Thanks.

```
    $pdf->Write( 6, $svg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP **TCPDF** supports `.svg` (http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Comment: Can this be used with FPDF?

Comment: TCPDF is a spin-off of FPDF. TCPDF is better maintained. If you are fixed on FPDF you can convert the `.svg`  to `.png` (svg2png, ImageMagick) and include this when generating the pdf instead of converting the .svg directly with the pdf tool. Here http://rhodopsin.blogspot.de/2009/11/php-class-adds-svg-images-to-pdf-files.html is aFPDF extensions to include svgs directly but i do not know if it works... If you are not fixed on FPDF you should consider to move to TCPDF if you have to include `.svg`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I never knew this existed! Thankfully I've got the SVG working, now I just need to convert the entire report to TCPDF format. Thanks again.

Comment: EPS might be better suited for converting SVG vectors. Instead of a rasterized format.

Answer (score 1):

FPDF does not support SVG as far as I know. But if you can convert your SVG vectors to EPS you can use ImageEps().

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script84.php